# Showing that $2z^4-3z^3+3z^2-z+1=0$ has no Real Roots

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

> I am trying to show that $$p(z)=2z^4-3z^3+3z^2-z+1=0$$ has no real roots.

From a previous related post, I incorrectly proposed the following:

Suppose $p(z)$ has a root on the real axes, then $p(x)=2x^4-3x^3+3x^2-x+1=0$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Now by the rational root theorem, the only possible roots that $p(x)$ can have is when $x=1$. But $p(1)\neq 0$ and hence $p(z)$ cannot have a root on the real axes by contradiction.

Alternatively, if we can show that $p(x)\geq 0$ or $p(x)\leq 0$, this would be sufficient to show that no real roots exist. But this is not obvious. I have also shown that $p(z)$ has no imaginary roots.

I am unsure of how to show that $p(z)$ does not have a real root.

Comment: a real root isn't always a rational root.

Comment: Yep, I agree. A real root could be $\sqrt{1912}$. If you are referring to my "incorrectly proposed" solution, then yes you are right.

Comment: FYI: Note that $p(-z)=2z^4+3z^3+3z^2+z+1$, which has no coefficient sign changes. By the [Descartes Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), there are no negative (real) roots. Unfortunately, the Rule isn't helpful here for the positive case: since $p(z)$ exhibits four coefficient sign changes, Descartes only tells us that there are $4$, $2$, or $0$ positive (real) roots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a real $z$ we have:
$$
2z^4-3z^3+3z^2-z+1
=
\underbrace{z^2(2z^2-3z+2)}_{\ge 0}+
\underbrace{z^2-z+1}_{>0}
>0\ .
$$

Comment: Quick question: Is $z^2(2z^2-3z+2)\geq 0$ as $z^2\geq 0$ and $2z^2-3z+2>0$?

Comment: @JulianAngussmith That looks like a reasonable way to reach that conclusion.

Comment: @JulianAngussmith Yes, i tried to split the polynomial, so that we have as a sufficient condition for positivity the fact that two polynomials of second degree are positive. (And one of them is involved so that we can write the strict inequality, the other one with a factor which is $\ge 0$.)

Answer (score 5):

I see the two threes in there, and I immediately think binomial theorem. To make those threes appear in the right degrees and with the right sign, you would need
$$
z(z-1)^3 = z^4 - 3z^3 + 3z^2 - z
$$
Thus we have
$$
p(z) = z(z-1)^3 + z^4 + 1
$$
Clearly $z^4 + 1$ is always greater than or equal to $1$. It remains to show that $z(z-1)^3>-1$. Since the only place $z(z-1)^3$ is negative is for $x\in (0,1)$, and on that interval, it's the product of one term between $0$ and $1$, and one term between $-1$ and $0$, we have our result.

Answer (score 3):

Note that$$P\left(x+\frac38\right)=2 x^4+\frac{21 x^2}{16}+\frac{13x}{32}+\frac{1901}{2048}.$$Since the discriminant of $\frac{21 x^2}{16}+\frac{13x}{32}+\frac{1901}{2048}$ is negative, $\frac{21 x^2}{16}+\frac{13x}{32}+\frac{1901}{2048}>0$ for each real number $x$. Therefore$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):P\left(x+\frac38\right)>0$$and this is equivalent to $(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):P(x)>0$.

Comment: How did you guess $\frac{3}{8}$would work?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Probably because the coefficient of $x^3$ is $-3$, and $2\cdot \binom{4}{1}\cdot\frac{3}{8}=3$ (here, $2$ is the leading coefficient).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It's just a matter of making the degree-3 term of $p(z + a)$ disappear. It's not very difficult to insert and solve, but it could've been pointed out explicitly.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If you have a polynomial $p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots a_ax+a_0$, then the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in $p\left(x-\frac{a_{n-1}}{na_n}\right)$ is always $0$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  Note that $$2z^4-3z^3+3z^2-z+1=2\,\left(z^2-\frac{3}4z\right)^2+\frac{15}{8}\,\left(z-\frac{4}{15}\right)^2+\frac{13}{15}\,.$$